# Custom angular components are rendered outside their containers

Tags: angular, extjs

Custom angular components are rendered outside their containers.

Example:

main.component.ts:

```
<ExtPanel
   title="main">
  <app-child></app-child>
</ExtPanel>
```

child.component.ts: selector: app-child

```
<ExtPanel
   title="child"></ExtPanel>
```

While displaying the main component, the child will be rendered outside the ExtPanel with the title "main".

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aht